# What is the oxidation state of iron at the photosynthetic reaction center?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, photosynthesis

Is the iron at the [reaction centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_reaction_centre)  in the $3^+$ or $2^+$ oxidation state?

For instance, 1AIG is $2^+$ or, perhaps it will depend upon charge separation state? I checked the PDB: some are $3^+$ while some are $2^+$.

Comment: At what reaction centre?

Comment: The question needs more information. The pH is critical to the answer.

Comment: Iron in these complexes is used to transfer electrons and so can exist in both oxidation states.

Comment: in chlorophyll it is Mg but in RC it is iron. I am asking the role of Fe. I don't care about Mg. I am not doing catalysis. By the way, what is the role of Mg?

Comment: How will PH influence the oxidize state? Just the normal living plants and bacteria. I saw in PDB various molecules. They marked out whether they are 3+ or 2+ ......I think they did not specify the PH?

Comment: Iron is fixed at the RC. It is not moving. It cannot transport electrons.

Comment: no....in the reaction center of (bacteria)  light harvesting antenna

Comment: Is there anything interesting about Fe in cytochromes?

Comment: @latra yes, Fe in cytochromes is also fixed, but it also functions to transport electrons. Like cytochrome c oxidase, or generally, all cytochromes in electron transport chain in respiration.